# $_SESSION[] manipulations

Tags: php, session

I am willing to implement in my project a menubar with some restrictions for a couple of users. I faced some difficulties when setting it up.

```
<?session_start();
$username=$_SESSION[username];
if($username == "usern1"){?>

<ul class="nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

   <? }elseif($username =="usern2"){?>
show just a half of this .nav


<?  }?>
```

PHP is selection what is first in this IF statement if I will change the order it will put the half menu .nav first.

Comment: Seperate your `<?php ?>` block and html.

Comment: In my code its separated. i cant edit here now(((

Comment: `$username=$_SESSION[username]`; should be `$username=$_SESSION['username'];`

Comment: change `$username=$_SESSION[username];` with `$username=$_SESSION["username"];`

Comment: var_dump($username); and its give me a value, i dont think that this is the solution thx

Comment: after nav element i have another restriction in the form they work perfectly, i have problem only with this menu... and i cant get why

Comment: @MihaiProcudin i just copy paste your code in my environment. its working fine. Only show 2 warnings that was just because of  using `$_SESSION[username];` instead of `$_SESSION["username"];`

Comment: ok let me show the origianl then ill will answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try following code**

```
   <?php
     session_start();
     $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    ?>
    <ul class="nav">
    <?php
        if($username == "usern1"){
    ?>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
       <?php
        } elseif ($username =="usern2") {
       ?>
         <!-- Add your li html menu here -->
       <?php
        }
       ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: i am very sorry or missing this php tags in my example, however in my original code they are present

Comment: the problem is that he is not switching, With rest of the code is ok he is working, only with menu I have this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?include ("scripts/DBconnection.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION[username])){
    header('location:login.php');
}else{
    $username = $_SESSION[username];//if I do something like this $username = "mike"it still show me the first if condition.... i dont get why...
}?>
<html>
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <ul class="....">
<?if($username == "roma" || "mark"){?>
        <li class="nav-item">
            ...
                </li>
                <li class="..">
                .
                </li>
                <li class="...">
                ...
                </li>
               </ul>
               <?}elseif($username == "mike"){?>
                <li class=".">
                .
            </li>
            <li class=".">
               .
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              .
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                .
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                .
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               .
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item pull-xs-right">
               .
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item pull-xs-right" style =" font-size:15px; padding-top:7px; padding-right:50px">
                .
            </li>

        </ul>
            <?}?>
```